# Access a String Resource from a sub-class

Tags: android, resources, subclass

How do I access a string resource from a subclass? Say a resource for use in a dialog that is a resource of the application that launches the dialog?

From within my application's `Activity` class I am creating a dialog

```
private void showNotice() {
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        }
    };

    try {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        //problem here
        builder.setMessage(getBaseContext().getResources().getString(R.string.dbNote))
        .setNeutralButton("OK", dialogClickListener).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: a subclass of what? could you explain a bit further...

Comment: you had better explain your problem in details ,or this would be closed by tie moderator.

Comment: Firgured it out. It was actually a problem with my resources themselves. I renamed the resource and it worked fine.

For what it's worth, I used the following to access the resource:

getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.msgNote);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.label_your_string);
```

Comment: I get an error that getContext() is undefined. It does offer getBaseContext(), but this does not work either.

Comment: Well, getBaseContext() should also work. What exactly do you mean by "not working". I assume that you are trying to access this string from inside a Dialog class, and not just any other class.